# how to replace a special character

Tags: python

how can I replace the indication of page numbers in the citations: `S.` with a colon (`:`)

example:

```
x = 'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, S. 115).'
```

-> '[...] (Durkheim 1984: 115).'

```
x = x.replace('S', '')
print(x)
Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, . 115).

x = x.replace('.', ':')
print(x)
Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [:::] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, : 115):
```

The first part removes the 'S' from the citation.
The second part removes every dot in the citation. It should just remove the dot within the brace.

Comment: `x.replace(', S.', ':')`…?

Comment: this is also works. very simple  x.split("S. ",1)[0] + x.split("S. ",1)[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with regex (will only replace the `S.` occurrences followed by a whitespace and digits) :

```
import re
>>> x = 'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, S. 115).'
>>> re.sub(r",\W*(S.)(\W*\d+)", ":\\2", x)
'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984: 115).'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace multiple characters at once.

```py
>>> x = 'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, S. 115).'
>>> x.replace('S.', ':')
'Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, : 115).'
```

As stated by [mhawke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21945/mhawke) 'S.' can exist somewhere else in the string and replace function will change all of them.

Assuming there are no other occurrences of 'S.' after the one we are going to replace, we can split string in reverse and join split parts with the character we want.

```py
>>> x = 'S. Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, S. 115).'
>>> ':'.join(x.rsplit('S.', 1))
'S. Laut Durkheim ist ein "soziologischer Tatbestand [...] individuellen Äußerungen unabhängiges Eigenleben besitzt" (Durkheim 1984, : 115).'
```

If not check [jarvis' answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644391/6453990)

Comment: What if the text also contained the string `S.` elsewhere? Seems a very real possibility to me.